# Toolbox containing no items when I'm editing a dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm maintainig an old MFC application with Visual Studio 2013. Building the application works fine, but I'm unable to use the dialog editor.

When I open a dialog from the resource view, it displays correctly, I can click on the existing items, view their properties, move them etc.

But when I open the toolbox via the View-Toolbox command (Ctrl+Alt+X), all I get is an empty toolbox as displayed below:

[image: empty toolbox]

- Right click on the toolbar and "Reset Toolbox" doesn't change anything
- Right click and then "Show all" shows an impressive list of tools, among those there is the Dialog Editor, but all items are inactive as shown in the picture below:

[image: toolbox with inactive items]

On the other hand when I create a new MFC project from scratch, the toolbox containing the dialog items works fine.

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?
FYI: in the meantime I use Visual Studio 6 (yes) for editing the resources.

Comment: Have you tried [deleting the ".tbd" files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49000a96-b43f-4320-b931-905aa14c35fc/missing-toolbox-conrols-do-a-reset-toolbox?forum=vcgeneral) at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0 ?  You'll need to close Visual Studio first.

Comment: @rrirower that helped, thanks. If you write this as an answer, I'll upvote it and accept it as answer.

Comment: Per your request, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two** typical work arounds to get the toolbox back in Visual Studio.  One is to reset the toolbox as you've tried.  The other is to [delete the “.tbd” files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49000a96-b43f-4320-b931-905aa14c35fc/missing-toolbox-conrols-do-a-reset-toolbox?forum=vcgeneral) in your corresponding *C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0* folder.